# AngularJS httpInterceptors and toastr

Tags: angularjs

I have an interceptor at the moment which handles my $http errors. It looks a bit like this:

```
.factory('RequestsErrorHandler', ['$q', '$injector', '$rootScope', 'ErrorService', function ($q, $injector, $rootScope, service) {
    var specificallyHandled = function (specificallyHandledBlock) {
        specificallyHandleInProgress = true;

        try {
            return specificallyHandledBlock();
        } finally {
            specificallyHandleInProgress = false;
        }
    };

    var responseError = function (rejection) {

        // Create the variable for handling errors
        var shouldHandle = (rejection && rejection.config && rejection.config.headers && rejection.config.headers['handle-generic-errors']);

        // If we should handle an error
        if (shouldHandle) {

            // Get our error
            var error = service.process(rejection);

            // Assign our error to the rootScope
            $rootScope.serverError = error;

            // Redirect to our error screen
            $injector.get('$state').transitionTo('error');
        }

        // Fallback, reject the promise
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    };

    return {
        specificallyHandled: specificallyHandled,
        responseError: responseError
    };
}])
```

I set this up in my app config like this:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', '$provide', function ($httpProvider, $provide) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('RequestsErrorHandler'); // Add our interceptor to handle http requests

    // Decorate $http to add a special header by default
    function addHeaderToConfig(config) {
        config = config || {};
        config.headers = config.headers || {};

        // Add the header unless user asked to handle errors himself
        if (!specificallyHandleInProgress) {
            config.headers['handle-generic-errors'] = true;
        }

        return config;
    }

    // The rest here is mostly boilerplate needed to decorate $http safely
    $provide.decorator('$http', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
        function decorateRegularCall(method) {
            return function (url, config) {
                return $delegate[method](url, addHeaderToConfig(config));
            };
        }

        function decorateDataCall(method) {
            return function (url, data, config) {
                return $delegate[method](url, data, addHeaderToConfig(config));
            };
        }

        function copyNotOverriddenAttributes(newHttp) {
            for (var attr in $delegate) {
                if (!newHttp.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
                    if (typeof ($delegate[attr]) === 'function') {
                        newHttp[attr] = function () {
                            return $delegate.apply($delegate, arguments);
                        };
                    } else {
                        newHttp[attr] = $delegate[attr];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var newHttp = function (config) {
            return $delegate(addHeaderToConfig(config));
        };

        newHttp.get = decorateRegularCall('get');
        newHttp.delete = decorateRegularCall('delete');
        newHttp.head = decorateRegularCall('head');
        newHttp.jsonp = decorateRegularCall('jsonp');
        newHttp.post = decorateDataCall('post');
        newHttp.put = decorateDataCall('put');

        copyNotOverriddenAttributes(newHttp);

        return newHttp;
    }]);
}])
```

now, this was working fine. But it started getting annoying going to a new view for every unhandled error. So instead I thought I might do it as a toastr error instead, so I changed my service to this:

```
.factory('RequestsErrorHandler', ['ErrorService', 'toastr', function (service, toastr) {
    var specificallyHandled = function (specificallyHandledBlock) {
        specificallyHandleInProgress = true;

        try {
            return specificallyHandledBlock();
        } finally {
            specificallyHandleInProgress = false;
        }
    };

    var responseError = function (rejection) {

        // Create the variable for handling errors
        var shouldHandle = (rejection && rejection.config && rejection.config.headers && rejection.config.headers['handle-generic-errors']);

        // If we should handle an error
        if (shouldHandle) {

            // Get our error
            var error = service.process(rejection);

            // Display the error
            toastr.error(error);
        }

        // Fallback, reject the promise
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    };

    return {
        specificallyHandled: specificallyHandled,
        responseError: responseError
    };
}])
```

but when I try to run this, I get an error stating:

> > Circular dependency found: $http <- $templateRequest <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- toastr <- RequestsErrorHandler <- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state

I am unsure of how to fix this, does anyone else know?

Answer (score 4):

There are two simple ways to solev that kind of circular dependency problem

1. decouple the services by using events: when an error is detected in the interceptor, broadcast an event (with the error information) on the root scope. In the `toastr` service (or in a service that uses toastr), listen on these events on the root scope and display them.
2. instead of injecting toastr in the interceptor, inject the $injector service. And when you need a toastr instance, call `$injector.get('toastr')`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Can you provide a brief explanation? I successfully implemented option #2 and want to be clear on what's preventing us normal DI approach.